# Como evitar a interseção de 2 objetos

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, jogos

Tenho um problema no jogo que estou a desenvolver.
O problema é o seguinte, tenho 2 aviões que conseguem ficar um em cima do outro e não sei o que fazer, alguma sugestão?

Código do avião1

```
int vBola=550;
int CBola=600;
Rectangle aviao11 = new Rectangle(vBola,CBola,x2,y2);
```

Código do avião2

```
int xBola=750;
int yBola=600;
Rectangle aviao22 = new Rectangle(xBola,yBola,x2,y2);
```

Um pequeno código para o avião não conseguir sair fora do ecrã

```
       if(!TeclasPressionadas[68].equals("")) 
       if (vBola>=1278)
       vBola = vBola +0;
               else
           vBola=vBola+7;
```

O meu problema é como implementar para os 2 aviões

Answer (score 2):

Crie métodos específicos para isso:

```
public static boolean colidiu(double a1, double w1, double a2, double w2) {
     return (a1 <= a2 && a2 <= a1 + w1) || (a2 <= a1 && a1 <= a2 + w2);
}

public static boolean colidiu(Rectangle a, Rectangle b) {
     return colidiu(a.getX(), a.getWidth(), b.getX(), b.getWidth())
             && colidiu(a.getY(), a.getHeight(), b.getY(), b.getHeight());
}
```

O primeiro método verifica se dois segmentos de reta na forma posição+comprimento colidem.

O segundo método serve para verificar se dois retângulos colidem. Eles colidem se as suas dimensões em X e em Y colidirem simultanemante.

No mais, devo avisar que a sua abordagem não parece ser uma boa abordagem orientada a objetos, mas isso é conteúdo para outra questão e exigiria saber mais do seu código para eu poder ao menos opinar melhor.